# Effects of default value for props that will be destructured in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, react-props

Let's say I have a simple component like this one (assume everything is imported properly):

```
const SpecialButton = (props) => {

    const { css, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <Button 
            className={`special-btn ${css}`}
            {...rest}
        >
            Click here
        </Button>
    );
};

SpecialButton.defaultProps = {
    css: '',
    rest: {}
};

SpecialButton.propTypes = {
    css: PropTypes.string,
    rest: PropTypes.object
}
```

I'm setting a default value of `{}` for the rest props and I'm also using object destructuring to pass it to the Button component.

So, assuming that who uses the SpecialButton is not passing anything else besides the css props, my questions are:

1. Since {} is an instance of the Object class, when I use the `...` does it dump all the properties of the Object into the Button component?
2. Is there any problem in not specifying a default value for the rest props?
3. Do you guys have a better suggestion about how to handle this case?

I'm adding the prop type and default prop for completeness, but I'm not 100% sure if I need to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are destructuring `css` and `rest params` from 'props'.

```
const { css, ...rest } = props;
```

Now the `rest` is not a property of props object, after destructuring it has all the props properties except for css property.

Edit: there is actually an "effect" of adding a "rest" prop to the defaultProps, this will result in the rest parameter to contain a `rest: {}` property and in turn passing that to the Button component in this example.

To answer your questions

> Since {} is an instance of the Object class, when I use the ... does
>   it dump all the properties of the Object into the Button component?

No, using spread operator gives only the user defined keys. So you won't find any properties of Object.

> Is there any problem in not specifying a default value for the rest
>   props?

As I said assigning a default value to rest params won't have any effect.

> Do you guys have a better suggestion about how to handle this case?

If you are passing the rest params to a child then it is not necessary to have the default props for the properties that will be present in rest params.

This is fine.

```
SpecialButton.defaultProps = {
    css: '',
};

SpecialButton.propTypes = {
    css: PropTypes.string,
}
```

Also use PropTypes.shape instead of PropTypes.object when you need to appy proptypes to objects.

Comment: Thank you @vs1682!